# Time-series vs sequence terminology

Tags: c++, time-series, data-mining

I'm developing a C++ class library for time-series modeling. I've run into some naming/terminology issues.  I am unsure whether I should name one of my template collection classes 'class series<>' or 'class sequence<>'.

Mathematically speaking a 'series' is the sum of a 'sequence', but when we speak of a 'time series' there is no sum involved!? I am wondering which part of the 'time series' is actually the 'series' (if any).

More specifically, imagine two columns in a table. One holds the time_points and the second the corresponding values. The C++ class I need to name holds the data from either of these columns. The class is however not used in the context of a 'table' but rather a 'model' or 'strategy'.

My question is: Am I technically wrong naming the class 'series'? Should it be named 'sequence' instead?

Comment: If i understand correctly your class holds 2 **containers**. one for time_points and the other for the corresponding values. Personally i think series is good enough. *However*, if each time_point corresponds with only one value and vice versa, i'd encapsulate them to a sruct/class called `TimeElement` or smth like that - that will hold **one** of each, and use `vector<TimeElement> timeSeries` to hold those pairs.

Comment: The class in question only holds the data, not the corrersponding time_points. This is because a model consists of potentially hundreds of series, and there is no point in duplicating the time_points for each one. The actual  time_point sequence is held once only at the model / strategy level.

Comment: I see, then your design with 'series' as the class name sounds good. I think it makes more sense albeit not being mathematically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no correct answer to your question, only opinions. So here is mine:

I've also coded such a class, and asked me exactly the same thing. I concluded that I find `Series` nicer than `Sequence`.

Moreover, I believe people -- particularly with little or no mathematic backgound -- do not make a difference here, but rather think of *Time-Series* when they hear *Series*.

Comment: +1. I don't know why time series are called series and not sequence, but they don't share anything with the mathematical concept of series. It's just a separate lexicon. Use time series, that is what people who implement and use them call them.